# Most efficient way to keep collection of string references

Tags: string, rust

What is the most efficient way to keep a collection of references to strings in Rust?

Specifically, I have the following as the beginning of some code to parse command line arguments (option parsing to be added):

```
let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
let mut files: Vec<&String> = Vec::new();
let mut i = 1;
while i < args.len() {
    let arg = &args[i];
    i += 1;
    if arg.as_bytes()[0] != b'-' {
        files.push(arg);
        continue;
    }
}
```

`args` is as recommended in https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch12-01-accepting-command-line-arguments.html declared as `Vec<String>`. As I understand it, that means new strings are constructed, which is mildly surprising; I would've expected that the command line arguments already exist in memory, and it would only be necessary to make a vector of references to the existing strings. But the compiler seems to concur that it needs to be `Vec<String>`.

It would seem inefficient to do the same for `files`; there is surely no need for further copying. Instead, I have declared it as `Vec<&String>`, which as I understand it, means only creating a vector of references to the existing strings, which is optimal. (Not that it makes a measurable performance difference for command line arguments, but I want to figure this out now, so I can get it right later when dealing with much larger data.)

Where I am slightly confused is that Rust seems to frequently recommend  `str` over `String`, and indeed the compiler is happy to have `files` hold either `str` or `&str`.

My best guess right now is that `str`, being an object that refers to a slice of a string, is most efficient when you want to keep a reference to just part of the string, but when you know you want the whole string, it is better to skip the overhead of creating a slice object, and just keep `&String`.

Is the above correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: *"when you know you want the whole string, it is better to skip the overhead of creating a slice object, and just keep &String"*. I don't know what you mean here but it's clearly not correct. Can you precise your meaning ? In any case, if you don't intend to change the string, there's zero benefit in having `&String` instead of `&str` in your vec.

Comment: @DenysSéguret As in, if you wanted to keep references to just parts of strings, slices would clearly be the way to do it (a slice, being a pointer plus length, is more efficient than copying the whole string). But if, as in the above, there is no requirement for *part* of a string, each reference will be to the entire original string, then is it more efficient still to go for `String&` because a simple pointer is more efficient than a pointer plus length?

Comment: @rwallace It's true that a `&str` slice is twice as large as `&String`, but `&String` needs two dereferences to get to the actual data, which is more work for the CPU and less memory locality. This is why `&str` is normally preferred - but you shoud measure which is better in your case. (Ideally with the actual data, not just command-line arguments.)

Comment: Technically, you can also go from `String` to `Box<str>` - the latter is a pointer plus length, like `&str`, while `String` is pointer plus length plus capacity. But I'd say that in most cases this wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: I guess that if you already have the owned strings the most efficient way is to not construct anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `args` is as recommended in https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch12-01-accepting-command-line-arguments.html declared as `Vec<String>`. As I understand it, that means new strings are constructed, which is mildly surprising; I would've expected that the command line arguments already exist in memory

The command-line arguments do exist in memory but

- they are not `String`, they are not even guaranteed to be UTF8
- they are not in a `Vec` layout

Fundamentally there isn't even any prescription as to their storage, all you know is they're C strings (nul-terminated) and you get an array of pointers to those, whose last element is a null pointer.

Which is why `args` is an *iterator* of `String`: it will lazily decode and validate each argument as you request it, in fact [you can check its source code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/env.rs.html#792-801):

```rust
pub fn args() -> Args {
    Args { inner: args_os() }
}
#[stable(feature = "env", since = "1.0.0")]
impl Iterator for Args {
    type Item = String;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<String> {
        self.inner.next().map(|s| s.into_string().unwrap())
    }
    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        self.inner.size_hint()
    }
}
```

Now I couldn't tell you why `args_os` yields `OsString` rather than `OsStr`, I would assume portability of some sort (e.g. some platforms might not guarantee the args data lives for the entirety of the program).

> My best guess right now is that str, being an object that refers to a slice of a string, is most efficient when you want to keep a reference to just part of the string, but when you know you want the whole string, it is better to skip the overhead of creating a slice object, and just keep &String.

> Is the above correct, or am I missing something?

`&String` exists only for regularity (in the sense that it's a natural outgrowth of shared references and `String` existing concurrently), it's not actually useful: an `&String` only lets you access readonly / immutable methods of `String`, all of which are really provided by `str` aside from `capacity()` (which is rarely useful) and a handful of methods duplicated from `str` to `String` (I assume for efficiency) like `len` or `is_empty`.

`&str` is also generally more efficient than `&String`: while its size is 2 words (pointer, length) rather than one (pointer), it points directly to the relevant data rather than pointing to a pointer to the relevant data (and requiring a dereference to access the length property). As such, `&String` is rarely considered useful and [clippy will warn against it by default](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/#ptr_arg) (also `&Vec` as `&[]` is usually better for the same reason).

Comment: *Now I couldn't tell you why args_os yields OsString rather than OsStr...* - On many OS'es the command-line arguments are globally accessible, e.g. there's `extern char *program_invocation_name` on Linux and `extern char **__argv` on [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/argc-argv-wargv?view=msvc-170)). Since such data is *mutable*, giving out `&OsStr` would open the possibility of UB if any C code mutated any of those (which would be otherwise perfectly safe from the perspectives of those languages).

Comment: @user4815162342 mutating argv is implementation behavior in C